# Parse a whole (beginning to end) string in C++, including all whitespace

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm looking for a way to generically parse a *whole* string in C++. What I mean by that is that the entire string is used in the parse, or else it's an error. This means that the naive `operator >>` behavior, which delimits on whitespace for most types, is not what I want (though I'd be perfectly happy if the solution involved it). Some examples:

```cpp
// Parse a whole value, throwing an exception if there's a parse error
void parse_into<typename T>(const char* input, T& result);

double value = 0;
parse_into("12.5", value);  // #1: Success
parse_into("ABC", value);  // #2: Fail
parse_into("12.5 abc", value);  //#3: Fail

std::string str_value;
parse_into("ABC", str_value);  // #4: Success
parse_into("ABC ABC", str_value);  // #5: Success; str_value == "ABC ABC"
parse_into("ABC  ABC", str_value);  // #6: Success; str_value == "ABC  ABC'
```

I'm confident that what I want revolves around `stringstream` and `operator >>`. I can see how to detect if not the whole string was parsed (case #3), by checking if the `stringstream` is empty. However, what I can't figure out is a generic way to allow for types that *can* be constructed from any string, like `std::string`. Perhaps a SIFNAE overload involving types that can be constructed from a `const char*`?

I don't have a particular formal requirement for the final interface; what I want is for it to do what feels like the "right thing" for any given type. For context, this is for a command-line argument parsing library. The library handles detecting word boundaries, so I know that the input to `parse_into` is the entire word I'm trying to read.

Comment: In other words, I'm looking to more-or-less exactly duplicate what `FromStr` does in Rust.

Comment: `operator>>` will work fine. Put the `std::string` into a `std::istringstream`, and then use `operator>>` to read from that.  You can then check whether the `std::istringstream` still has any unread data if the read is successful. All you need is overloads of `operator>>` for whatever types you are interested in reading from the `std::string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `operator >>` fails test cases 5 and 6

Comment: unless you specialize `parse_into()` to not use `operator>>` when parsing into a `std::string` variable, eg: `void parse_into<typename T>(const char* input, T& result) { istringstream iss(input); if (!(iss >> result) || (iss.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)) throw ...; }` `void parse_into<std::string>(const char* input, std::string& result) { result = input; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `double` this can be achieved with [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) after first reading your input as `std::string`.

```
std::optional<double> parse(std::string const& str) {
  std::size_t num = 0;
  try {
    auto const res = std::stod(str,&num);
    if (num < str.size()) return std::nullopt;
    return res;
  } catch (...) {
    return std::nullopt;
  }
}
```

You can create overloads (using a passed in out value, for example) for different types. I'm using an [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) here, but you can also `throw` or use any other means of communicating an error.

For instance:

```
bool parse(std::string const& str, double& out);
bool parse(std::string const& str, std::uint32_t& out);
bool parse(std::string const& str, std::string& out); // always succeeds
// ...
```

---

**Edit**: A more general interface that allows to pass any type of `stoXYZ` function:

```
  template <typename T>
  static void parse(std::string const& s, T (*fun)(std::string const&,std::size_t*,int), std::optional<T>& out) { /**/ }   
  template <typename T>
  static void parse(std::string const& s, T (*fun)(std::string const&,std::size_t*), std::optional<T>& out) { /**/ }
```

This takes a pointer-to-function, but it could also take a `std::function` object. The two overloads exist because `std::stoi` and `std::stod` have different argument lists (the integer ones want a base).

Comment: This looks great, actually. Is there a way I can allow my client users to also create overloads that will be seen by my library, if they want to parse their own types?

Comment: Yes, actually this is an excerpt from a utility library I once wrote (which is too long to post here). You can write a general purpose parse function that also takes a function object `f` as argument. This `f` will then do the actual job, so for `double` you'd pass `std::stod` and for the other built-in types their corresponding converter. Your user could then create a function with an interface similar to that and pass that to your general `parse` function.

Comment: @bitmask what is the point of `num` in your code? It is being assigned to 0 and never reassigned, but you check it against `str.size()`, so `if (num <str.size())` will always be true for a non-empty `str`. Perhaps you meant `auto const res = std::stod(str, &num);` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I messed up and forgot to actually pass it to `std::stod`. Fixed.